# Failing to render chart – "can't acquire context from the given item"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am attempting to load a chart from the charts.js library on my Vue.js and Vuetify application, but the following error is shown:

> Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Then when I attempt to addon the function of .getContext("2d) it does not resolve the error. The mounted method seems to be working fine, as I have got other functions running without any issues and everything seems to be imported correctly. I have tried with JQUERY, but the same error still persists.

Here my files for reference:
app.vue:

Canvas from template:

```
 <canvas id="charting" width="600px" height="600px">
 </canvas>
```

app.vue JS:

```
 <script>
 import Chart from '../../../../node_modules/chart.js'
 import coinCharts from './scripts/charts/randomcoin.js'

 export default {
 data() {
 return {
 coinCharts: coinCharts
 }
 },
 methods: {
 createChart(id, chartData) {
 const ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");
 const chartRender = new Chart(ctx, {
 type:chartData.type,
 data:chartData.data,
 options: chartData.options
 })}
 },

 mounted() {
 this.createChart("charting", this.coinCharts);
 }
 }
```

Imported script with chart data:

```
export const coinCharts =  new Chart({
type: 'line',

data: {
labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
datasets: [{
label: 'My First dataset',
backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
}]
},

options: {
responsive:true,
lineTension:1
}
})

export default coinCharts;
```

On compiling, the following error is displayed:

```
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
error: 'chartRender' is assigned a value but never used (no-unused-vars) 
at src\components\views\coins\AlphaCoin.vue:50:11:
createChart(id, chartData) {
const ctx = document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");
const chartRender = new Chart(ctx, {
type:chartData.type,
data:chartData.data,
options: chartData.options
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem your calling a `new Chart()` twice. Once on your chart Data `randomcoin.js` and also on your `createChart(id, chartData)` method. Try to change your chart Data to an object like this:

```
export const coinCharts = {
type: 'line',

data: {
  labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
  }]
},

options: {
  responsive:true,
  lineTension:1
}
}

export default coinCharts;
```

This should solve your problem.